# Getting Insufficient Privileges error on Cases as System Admin and Record Owner

Tags: insufficient-privileges, record-owner, system-admin

I came across an org where the system admin users are receiving insufficient privileges error while trying to access case records. I don't understand why admin users are getting this error as 'View All Data' and 'Modify All Data' are checked by default at profile level. In the list view, I'm able to see the case owners. So, I logged in as a case owner and tried to access the cases owned by the user. Still receiving the same insufficient privileges error. Any thoughts on what I should be looking at to fix this?

Comment: Any chance the case view is overridden with a VF page that the profile does not have access to?

Comment: I checked it, the view is not overridden. I created some cases for testing and I'm able to view them.

Comment: So you can view any new cases created by yourself, but you can't view any old cases created by anyone? What about the user? Can they create/view their own new case and just not access the old ones? Are there multiple record types in play? What is the OWD for Case object?

Comment: OWD for case object is Private. Yes, there are multiple record types, but all the record types are assigned to the profile.

Comment: if you do a soql query on the Case, can you see it? If yes, does it have a recordTypeId for a no-longer existing recordType (although this shouldn't happen)

Comment: @cropredy I created a with sharing class for my testing and added a query in it which is returning records, but when try to open the same records in UI, it throws insufficient privileges error. The record type still exists and it is assigned to my profile.

Comment: I liked Eric's idea that the page references something the sysad doesn't have access to (like a VF page)  But try SOQL directly in developer console too

Comment: @cropredy I did query directly in Query Editor. I'm able to access the records that I'm unable to view through UI. And there is no Visualforce override for view. It is using standard page. I also checked the security of all the 69 Visualforce pages and they all are enabled for System Admin profile.

Comment: create a copy of the page layout with all sections removed and assign to the system admin profile; Can you still not view?